# Настройка стилей после загрузки страницы

Tags: javascript, webpack

Собираю проект через webpack. Когда открываю страницу - вместо анимации "выплывания" текста происходит настройка стилей, таких как увеличение размера текста, закругление углов кнопки и т.д(указывал в стилях transition:1s, суть анимации в transform:translateY() вверх и opacity с 0 до 100). Я так полагаю это из-за того, что стили подключаются в js и анимации происходят одновременно с загрузкой стилей. Как это исправить?
Копирую html с помощью HTMLWebpackPlugin в папку dist, webpack создаёт index.js файл, который сам подключается в index.html.
Мой webpack.config, может быть будет полезен:

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const {CleanWebpackPlugin} = require('clean-webpack-plugin')
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
 
module.exports = {
    context:path.resolve(__dirname,'src'),
    mode: 'development',
    entry: './js/index.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'index.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './index.html'
        }),
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
        new CopyWebpackPlugin(
            {
                patterns: [
                    {
                        from: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/img'), to: path.resolve(__dirname,'dist/img'),
                    }
                ]
            }
        )
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test:/\.css$/,
                use:['style-loader','css-loader']
            },
            {
                test:/\.(png|jpg|svg|gif|webm)$/,
                use: ['file-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ["@babel/preset-env"]
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```